# Get connection string from db and use it at runtime result in System.NullReferenceException

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string

I have a master/parent web project, in master page I have this:

```
 Public dbGiano As New dbGianoEntities
 Public cliente As Clienti = dbGiano.Clienti.Where(Function(c) c.id = 1).SingleOrDefault
```

In the parent page aspx I have declared

```
<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/Site1.master"%>
```

and on vb:

```
Public Class badge
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim strcon As String = ""
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(Master.cliente.dbConnectionString).ConnectionString.ToString
            bindGrid(grdBadge)
        End If
    End Sub
```

When I run it I receive an error:
System.NullReferenceException
System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned Nothing.

But I really don't understand why, in debug I clearly see that Master.cliente.dbConnectionString contain a valid connection string in the form "Data Source=192.168.2.xx\sqlexpress2012;Initial Catalog=dbxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx"

[image]

This is making me insane because the same approach works in another project

Comment: *"the same approach works in another project"*. No it doesn't. You say that `Master.cliente.dbConnectionString` contains a connection string. In that case, why are you using it as a key to get a connection string from your config file? That makes no sense. If you use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` then you're supposed to provide the name of a connection string stored in the config file. Do you have a config file? Do you have connection string in that config file? What is the name used for it in that config file? is that the value that `Master.cliente.dbConnectionString`? No.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for your comment, clearly I remembered uncorrectly... my objective is to open a connection to use sql syntax (not entity framework) at runtime, I want to read the connection string from a db on the fly based on the logged user. What I have to use instead of configuration manager? I have no connection string saved in web.config and that's ok

Comment: Based on what you posted, your connection string is in `Master.cliente.dbConnectionString` so use that. Just assign that directly to `strcon`.

Comment: I did that and it's working, -.-' sorry